# url function in jinja2 template throws AttributeError in Django

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I have a `base.html` in `my_project/jinja2/` and it contains everything except the `<body>` for a site.  We then extend `base.html` as one does.

In this example I am extending `base.html` from app `people` in a file at `my_project/people/jinja2/people/people_list.html` using something like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Some html -->
{% endblock content %}
```

My `base.html` includes a link to the blog rss feed in the `<head>` like so:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Blog" href="{{ url('blog:articles_feed') }}" />
```

This works fine most places such as `my_project/jinja2/index.html` and `my_project/jinja2/blog_list.html` but in this 3rd app `people`, I am getting the following error at this same line of template code:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__call__'
```

Since jinja2 has better debugging I can run python in werkzueg and see some potential details of what might be happening:

```
locals()
```

which outputs:

```
{
    '_': {...},
    'static': < bound method StaticFilesStorage.url of < django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f423ec3ebe0 >> ,
    'joiner': < class 'jinja2.utils.Joiner' > ,
    'request': < WSGIRequest: GET '/case-studies/hog?__debugger__=yes&cmd=locals()&frm=139922493301984&s=XfAagGnpxRWFBRRd0Uzk' > ,
    'page': None,
    'csrf_input': < django.utils.functional.lazy. < locals > .__proxy__ object at 0x7f423e8262e8 > ,
    'cycler': < class 'jinja2.utils.Cycler' > ,
    'dict': < class 'dict' > ,
    'absolute_url': < function absolute_url at 0x7f423ece5b70 > ,
    'lipsum': < function generate_lorem_ipsum at 0x7f423ebfc8c8 > ,
    'view': < leaf.views.LeafTemplateView object at 0x7f423e820198 > ,
    'range': < class 'range' > ,
    'ngettext': < function ungettext at 0x7f42450547b8 > ,
    'gettext': < function ugettext at 0x7f4245054730 > ,
    'absolute_root': < function absolute_root at 0x7f423ece8268 > ,
    'datetime': < class 'datetime.datetime' > ,
    'csrf_token': < django.utils.functional.lazy. < locals > .__proxy__ object at 0x7f423e826400 > ,
    'url': 'people/all'
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a correct assumption, but is `url` not being correctly added to the environment as a function, but a string instead?  It's in my jinja2.py file, and works elsewhere as expected in jinja2 templates.  What gives?

Comment: You might be passing a context variable also called `url` in  your `people` view.

Comment: Interesting point.  I hadn't considered something like this.  I set this up in the `people` app with a url route like: `url(r'^people-list/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="people_list.html")),`.  From [Django source for TemplateView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/views/generic/base.py#L152), I don't see `TemplateView` adding a `url` context variable.  Using jinja, would anything else be adding context unexpectedly for just this view (it works fine in some other views).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selcuk had the right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462937/url-function-in-jinja2-template-throws-attributeerror-in-django#comment60543553_36462937).  I was using jinja templates, and the `kwargs` are added in automatically.  One of my `kwargs` was `<url>` and was over-riding the `url` extension I had added to the jinja environment.  Renaming the `kwarg` to something else solved the issue.